WordApp.Documents.Content.Find isn' working
I am new to VBA programming and I have a problem. I am trying to automatice words documents. I have a template document with generic names and I need to use a VBA code in excel to replace those generic names with concrete names. The problem is when I use the .Find function either way it does not work. I made a simple example in which I printed on the debug screen a couple of lines that does not use the mentioned function but when I use it, it does not print. That is to say the result of the following code is this:
Texto a buscar: NOMBRE
Reemplazo: hello
Thank you
Sub Prueba2()
    Dim WordApp As Object               'Aplicación Word
    Dim PlantillaDoc As Object          'Word plantilla
    
    ' Inicializar la aplicación de Word
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    WordApp.Visible = True     'Solo para depurar
    
    Set PlantillaDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\alsanchez\Documents\Automatización de Proyectos\adsgasdfg\Nuevo Documento de Microsoft Word.docx")

    ' Configuración de búsqueda
    Dim TextoBuscado As String
    Dim ReemplazoTexto As String
    
    TextoBuscado = "NOMBRE"
    ReemplazoTexto = "hello"
    
    Debug.Print "Texto a buscar: " & TextoBuscado
    Debug.Print "Reemplazo: " & ReemplazoTexto
    Debug.Print "Dirección de búsqueda: " & IIf(PlantillaDoc.Find.Forward, "Hacia adelante", "Hacia atrás")
    Debug.Print "Envolver búsqueda: " & IIf(PlantillaDoc.Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue, "Sí", "No")
    Debug.Print "Coincidir mayúsculas/minúsculas: " & IIf(PlantillaDoc.Find.MatchCase, "Sí", "No")

    'Reemplazo del texto de la plantilla por nombres concretos
    PlantillaDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting
    PlantillaDoc.Content.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With PlantillaDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = TextoBuscado
        .Replacement.Text = ReemplazoTexto
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    
    ' Ejecutar búsqueda y reemplazo
    PlantillaDoc.Content.Find.Execute Replace:=2
    
End Sub


Two things:
Your Debug.Print statements using an invalid object. You write IIf(PlantillaDoc.Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue, "Sí", "No"), but PlantillaDoc.Find doesn't exist. It must be PlantillaDoc.Content.Find. Or, even better, move those statements within your With-block and write
With PlantillaDoc.Content.Find
    Debug.Print "Dirección de búsqueda: " & IIf(.Forward, "Hacia adelante", "Hacia atrás")
    Debug.Print "Envolver búsqueda: " & IIf(.Wrap = wdFindContinue, "Sí", "No")
    Debug.Print "Coincidir mayúsculas/minúsculas: " & IIf(.MatchCase, "Sí", "No")
    (...)

As you are using Late Binding, the compiler cannot tell you that problem - my advice is to use Early Binging instead.
And as you are using On Error Resume Next, the runtime errors are not displayed and instead, the Print-statement are simply skipped - my advice is to never use On Error Resume Next (except for a single statement where you expect and know that is may fail).
Okay, but the real issue why nothing is replaced is simple: You set all the Find-parameter, but you forgot to execute the Find/Replace. Add the following statement to the code:
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


Thank you very much. I have applied your comments and the result has improved but it has not worked at all. When giving a value to TemplateDoc.Content.Find.Text it doesn't hold, and before End with the value becomes “”
With PlantillaDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = TextoBuscado
    .Replacement.Text = ReemplazoTexto
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
End With

Debug.Print "Text =" & PlantillaDoc.Content.Find.Text

Result: Text =

Sorry, but code in comments is hardly readable - please update your original question with the new code.

I'm sorry, I'm not cut out on this. Searching the internet I finally found the error.
It was I was using PlantillaDoc.Content.Find insead of PlantillaDoc.Range.Find
Thank you very much anyway, you are very kind

@ÁlvaroSánchezGómez - There is no difference between PlantillaDoc.Content.Find and PlantillaDoc.Range.Find . Both point to exactly the same thing. The values you assign to the properties of Find do not get set until Find.Execute is run
